# Ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64 doesn't go past installation type

Tags: system-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-64Bit. I checked `md5sum` of the ISO and it's correct.
I tried creating the boo-table USB flash with `pendrivelinux` or `unetbootin` Windows.
Check disk for defects gives me no errors.

In the boot menu I choose install Ubuntu and get to the choose installation type option (I select Install Ubuntu alongside) => click install and this triggers restart => I get back to the initial menu (Try Ubuntu, install Ubuntu, check disk for defects...).

Comment: Can you give us a little more information about your hardware? CPU, GPU, Motherboard, HDD / SSD configuration, UEFI Bios or leagacy BIOS?

Comment: Processor: Intel Core i5-2410M CPU 2.30GHz 2.30GHz
4GB DDR3 Memory , 750GB HDD , NVIDIA GeForce GT 540M

Comment: Okay, thanks, you might check in your BIOS to disable UEFI and set it to legacy Bios / Boot. 2nd you should disable SecureBoot in your Bios (sometimes you find this option as "Windows 8 Options"). 3rd you should disable Fastboot in your Bios. After all that try to Boot your flash drive and select "Verify disk integrity" after it's finished (without error) reboot, select the stick and let it boot to the Ubuntu live environment (don't select Install Ubuntu -> select try Ubuntu without installing). Then you should be able to install Ubuntu with the installer on the desktop.

Comment: btw I have windows 7 and I checked C:\Windows\Panther\setupact.log => Callback_BootEnvironmentDetect: Detected boot environment:BIOS , so I don't think I have to do what you described ? I tried the "try without installing option" and the same result... The disk check gives me no errors. I also tried on another computer with almost the same hardware params but running win 8 and it goes past the select "installation type" so I guess the bootable flash is ok. Do you have any other suggestions ? Maybe I should install an older version of ubuntu?